# The best LDAP browser in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, browser, ldap

I'm using [phpLDAPadmin](http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/) currently, but I'm wondering if there is any native utility do the similar thing?

Comment: Is this just a product recommendation request?

Comment: @NathanBasanese yes it is.

Comment: Based on four answers bellow, I do not see a satisfactory answer. I will stay in ldapvi , a command-line to easily edit the files, and ldap2dot.py, to generate dot files to compile  graphs.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

[Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) is is an excellent LDAP/LDIF browser and editor. It is under active development and is extensible.

Comment: I agree. It's the most complete and reliable I've ever tried.

Comment: Thanks @Terry Gardner, i never saw this one before. We'll check it out.

Comment: The download is 140MB heavy.

Comment: Apache Directory Studio just throws a couple of exceptions. And even worse, it is based on Eclipse.

Answer (score 8):

It hasn't been updated in several centuries, but we still use LBE, LDAP Browser/Editor.  It's Java based, and we use on both Linux and Windows (from the same install base actually) so I don't know if you consider that 'native'.

http://www.novell.com/communities/node/8652/gawors-excellent-ldap-browsereditor-v282

Comment: Also works on a Mac.

Comment: I struggle to get this working with TLS, but for all purposes, LBE is my LDAP goto tool.

Answer (score 5):

I have always used below LDAP browsers.

JXplorer (http://jxplorer.org/index.html) is very handy & good when you want to manage cn=config database format.

phpLDAPadmin Web based LDAP browser - add, edit, delete or view records. Written in PHP - mature and actively developed. GNU license. Very powerful.

Answer (score 2):

One can also try to use [Luma](http://luma.sourceforge.net/)